# Problem of PATH using Git on Windows. It's looking for .ssh into /home/Users/ while it's in C:/Users/

Tags: windows, git, github, git-clone

I have just had a new PC and have decided to keep it under Windows 11. I installed Git and yesterday I could clone my project. But today I couldn't push anymore
.
So I've tried a lot of things to solve my problem and now I am stuck.

Here is the thing :

Using Git Bash, I can check the ssh connexion to github but I have a message specifying it didn't find the repository .ssh (because it's looking for it at /home/Users/... while it's at C:/Users/remip/.ssh) but the connexion works :

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Could not create directory '/home/remip/.ssh' (No such file or directory).
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/remip/.ssh/known_hosts).
Hi policetr! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

However if i am doing the same thing on windows Powershell, I don't have the path problem :

```
PS C:\Users\remip> ssh -T git@github.com
Hi policetr! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But if I try to clone or push :

```
PS C:\Users\remip\Documents\Test\policetr.github.io> git pull                                                           The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.                                              ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.                                          This key is not known by any other names.                                                                               Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes                                                Could not create directory '/home/remip/.ssh' (No such file or directory).                                              Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/remip/.ssh/known_hosts).                                       git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).                                                                          fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                                                                                                                                   Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                     and the repository exists.
```

Another strange point is that I can pull/push in another project

```
PS C:\Users\remip\Documents\JAYA\Labo_versite> git pull                                                                 remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.                                                                                   remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.                                                                             remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0                                                            Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), 653 bytes | 163.00 KiB/s, done.                                                          From https://github.com/BaptisteAmare/Labo_versite                                                                         beb0e76f..b5cfa1eb  main       -> origin/main                                                                        Updating beb0e76f..b5cfa1eb                                                                                             Fast-forward                                                                                                             node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache                   |   2 +-                                                             node_modules/.cache/default-development/0.pack     | Bin 23112012 -> 23126041 bytes                                     node_modules/.cache/default-development/1.pack     | Bin 47171 -> 39336828 bytes                                        node_modules/.cache/default-development/index.pack | Bin 1657622 -> 1763212 bytes                                       .../.cache/default-development/index.pack.old      | Bin 1657481 -> 1762956 bytes                                       src/components/Section.js                          |   3 ---                                                            6 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 4 deletions(-)
```

What I have done trying to solve the problem :

edit .ssh/config :

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile C:/Users/remip/.ssh/id_rsa
  UserKnownHostsFile C:/Users/remip/.ssh/known_hosts
  User git
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

edit .bash_profile and .bashrc:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add /c/Users/remip/.ssh/id_rsa

export SSH_HOME=C:/Users/remip/.ssh
export HOME=C:/Users/remip
```